# ArcGIS Kernel Density with polyline, search radius / bandwidth calculation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, linestring

I'm conducting a density analysis of a series of polylines and I'm hung up on determining an appropriate search radius.

The default calculation performed by arcgis is to take the shorter dimension of the input feature extent divided by 30. However, I would prefer to use the formula set forth by Bailey and Gatrell in Interactive Spatial Data Analysis (1995).

They suggest that the bandwidth for a kernel analysis be set to 0.68n^(-0.2) where n=the number of features being analyzed.

This calculation is straightforward for points as each point is the same size. However, the polyline dataset I am working with has lines of varying length. Simply taking the number of lines as n doesn't seem appropriate.

I have considered converting the polylines to points but before I begin with this approach I am curious if there might be other valid approaches?

Comment: +1 This is a great question. Bandwidths do matter, and there are indeed procedures to determine good ones as well as rules of thumb like the B&G one. But ultimately they are all in conflict, and this is because a good choice of bandwidth depends on the nature of the data and the purpose of the analysis. Could you perhaps share more information about what these polylines represent and what the density analysis aims to do?

Comment: Sure. The polyines represent river features. There is a separate layer of points of interest. The intent of the density analysis is to create a raster file on which the points of interest file will be overlaid. The raster value at each point of interest will then be extracted using the Extract Values to Point tool. Thanks.

Comment: How will these values be interpreted?  What is their meaning?  What are they intended to tell us about the relationship between the points of interest and the rivers?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how they will be used. I'm doing this work under contract and only have a few details about the project. My understanding is that the intent to create a measure of how "in the creeks" each point of interest is in. My assumption is that the extracted value will ultimately be used in a regression model, but I don't know specifics. Sorry, not a very satisfying or useful answer but I've only been given limited information at this point.

Comment: It sounds like you should go back to the client and find these things out.  Otherwise what they get may be worse than useless--it might be totally wrong for their intended application.

Comment: Fair enough. However, the question I asked had to do with issues determining a search radius while using polyline features. If the number of features is a factor in determining the radius, what is the best way to handle lines where segment lengths differ (sometimes significantly so)?

Comment: The number of features may be a factor when those features have been *sampled* from a larger population and the purpose is to estimate some property of that population. That does not seem to be the case here: your features constitute an exhaustive representation of all the creek beds and the density appears intended to represent some kind of (undefined) relationship between the creeks and the points of interest, such as being visible, being susceptible to flood, being within a riparian habitat, etc. I maintain that this *relationship* determines appropriate radii to use.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. The points in this case represent towns. It would be ideal to have some value derived from other research that would help determine a meaningful distance. But that data is not available. Thanks for clarifying. I have gone back to client to get clarification and I'll post back when I know more.

Comment: In the study area, rivers are important means of transport. So areas with higher river density are expected to see more of certain types of activity and visa versa. Given this, any thoughts on determining an appropriate search radius? Thanks.

Comment: You need to develop a measure of "geographic accessibility to rivers." Ideally this would depend on the overland routes taken to rivers and the river navigability: just having lots of little streams in the area wouldn't be much help, nor would it be much help if major waterfalls lay just downstream. (Such considerations explain the pattern of urbanization throughout the southeastern coast of the US, for instance.) Such an accessibility measure *might* depend partially on river density, but I suspect that a *cost-distance* calculation would be more pertinent and useful.

Comment: With no answers after nearly 4 years, if this question is still of interest to you I think you should use the advice from comments to try and heavily revise it into something more answerable.